# Is maven having any life cycle to run scripts?

Tags: maven, automation, maven-lifecycle

I want to know whether maven has different lifecycle for run scripts .  please help me to know the answer to this question "Is maven having any life cycle to run scripts?"

Comment: Yes there are 23 goals and 7 phases in 1 lifecycle  of a maven project. You have to be specific in asking question. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please tell us what your script is doing and we can tell you the right phase.

Comment: You probably just want the [Exec Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) which could be used to run a script and attached to a specific phase.